# « Que s'il avait s'agit » vs « que s'il s'agissait »

Tags: conjugaison, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

> 1/ Elle me paraitra aussi différente que s’il s’agissait d’une culture
>   d’un pays lointain.

Ou

> 2/ Elle me paraitra aussi différente que s’il avait s’agit d’une
>   culture d’un pays lointain. ("s'était s'agit" sonne bizarrement)

J’aimerais utiliser la deuxième phrase, mais est-elle correcte?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *Il s'était agi* pour conjuguer *s'agir* au plus-que-parfait.
- J'ai tendance à préférer le plus-que-parfait même s'il est en théorie utilisé pour des faits antérieurs à un autre fait passé, et qu'il n'y en a pas ici.  J'ai cherché dans Grevisse et n'ai rien trouvé de pertinent.

Comment: "Elle me paraîtra aussi différente que s’il s'était agi d’une culture d’un pays lointain" → Elle me parait bien étrange, peut-être théoriquement correcte, mais maladroite. Je n'ai jamais entendu de "s'était agi". Merci pour ta correction ! Ps: que penses-tu de la réponse de GAM?

Answer (score 1):

Si la question est de savoir si la phrase (2) correspond à la norme telle que représentée par les grammaires, sans doute qu'elle n'est pas correcte.

Si il s'agit de savoir si elle correspond à l'usage francophone, elle est bien attestée. En pratique, *s'agir* se comporte comme si il avait été réanalysé comme *sagir* de la même façon que *s'en aller* se comporte quasiment comme *s'enaller* :

> Lise a pleuré quand il s'est en allé. (=> *enallé*) 
>    Marcia l'a giflée quand il a s'agit d'en parler. (=> *sagi*)

Si *sagir* n'est pas perçu comme un verbe essentiellement pronominal, son passé composé suit le modèle de *finir*.

Indépendamment des temps composés, le même problème se manifeste avec les temps simples et les clitiques :

> Dans ce livre, il ne s'agissait de rien dire.
>   => *il n'y s'agissait de rien* vs *il ne s'y agissait de rien*
>   Il ne s'agissait pas de celà.
>   => *il n'en s'agissait pas* vs *il ne s'en agissait pas*

Pour *s'en aller*, le changement reste incomplet à l'impératif avec *va-t'en* qui subsiste sur le modèle de *s'en aller* plutôt que *enva-toi* sur le modèle de *s'enaller*.

Comment: J'imagine qu'il y a une typo sur le participe passé. N'est-ce pas « agi » (ce qui est le défaut pour _agir_ et demeure valable si on suit le modèle de _finir_) ?

Comment: Tout à fait, mais pour l'instant, la réanalyse ne s'est pas manifestée dans l'orthographe. Les gens qui disent ilasaZi utilisent *s'agit* qui est la seule forme disponible pour le moment.

Comment: Merci pour l'information. Une deuxième raison pour moi de ne pas aimer cette forme (oui, j'ai mes moments intégristes).

Comment: Ça n'a rien à voir avec l'intégrisme.,,

Comment: Comparez *s'il en s'agissait* avec *s'il s'en agissait*. La deuxième tournure est attestée au 19ème mais semble avoir considérablement perdu du terrain depuis. La première correspond à la réanalyse...